# Traversing trees in SQL: JOINs vs imperative algorithm

Tags: graphs, sql

I have a table representing posts on a message board. Posts may or may not have parents.

What is the most common way to get all posts starting from a given post, or to find the root post of any given post?

I can think of using JOINs to join parents and children, but how can I know how many joins I need before I stop?

Comment: Can you share the table structure? What database are you using? Have you looked into recursive CTEs (common table expressions)?

Comment: You should post this on DBA or StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

There are several models for holding hierarchical data in a relational database. There's a good summary [here](http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data). In summary they are

- Adjacency list: each row contains a foreign key to its parent. Fast for structure changes. Requires recursive processing to find the base ancestor.
- Path enumeration: each node stores its ancestry. An update requires all children to be updated. For a known node reaching the root requires no further work.
- Nested sets: additional columns hold the ancestry. The cost of structure changes depends on how big the moving subtree is. The root node is fast to find.
- Closure table: store all ancestor-descendant pairs. Structure changes can be expensive. Root node expensive to identify.

From the given information a path enumeration sounds like your best option.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link. I have been using adjacency list but did not know all the technical names of the others.